# Encrypt file in Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I created the algorithm to encrypt and decrypt a string in Perl ( using AES in CFB mode). Now I want to extend to encryption to file level. How should I get the content of the file? What would be a good approach?

1. Read the file normally
   `open(my $fh, "<", "myTestFile.ext");`
2. Read the file in binmode 
   `open(my $fh, "<", "myTestFile.ext");
   binmode $fh`

Then how should I store the content of the files?

a) Read all the content of the file in one string and provide the string to the implemented program

```
my $document = do {
    local $/ = undef;
    <$fh>; # file handle opened previously
};
encryptionAlgorithm($document);
```

b) Read the content of the file line by line

```
while( my $line = <$fh>)
{
    encryptionAlgorithm($line);
}
```

In both cases should I chomp the `\n`'s ?

Answer (score 2):

AES encrypts blocks of 128 bits (16 bytes), so you'll want to read your file 16 bytes at a time. To do this, you need to `binmode` your file, then read it with the [`read`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) builtin:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myTestFile.ext' or die $!;
binmode $fh;

while (read($fh,my $block,16)) {
    # encrypt $block
}
```

Note that I've added `or die $!` after opening the file: you want to always make sure your `open` worked.

Also, don't forget that if the block you read is less than 16 bytes long, you'll have to do some padding. (I don't recall how the blocks are padded for AES, but I trust you do since you are implementing it)

---

About the approaches you thought of:

- Reading the entire file at once will potentially consume a lot of memory if the file is big.
- Reading the file line by line: if the file contains no newline, then you'll read it entirely at once, which might consume a lot of memory. And if lines contain a number of bytes which isn't a multiple of 16, then you'll have to combine bytes from different lines, which will require more work than simply reading blocks of 16 bytes.

Also, you definitely don't want to `chomp` anything! You should have `decrypt(encrypt(file)) == file`, but if you `chomp` the newlines, that won't be the case anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and for the solution. I am new to the topic and I have to do a school project